# Most efficient web.config redirect

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5

I have a set of folder redirects that send users to external sites.

For example:

```
site.com/folder --> www.cnn.com
site.com/folder2 --> www.foxnews.com
```

This setup seems to work ok, except that it has caught images as well, rather than just folders.

```
 <rule name="NAME_zoom1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/folder" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="https://cnn.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Is there a better formed rule that can related only to first level folders (`site.com/folder` and not `site.com/images/folder`)? and no less important - to match only folder and not an image that might have the word "folder" in it (which is happening now)

**UPDATE:**
I need to be sure that `folder` and `folder1` do not get caught in the same rule, which they do, and adding `^` does not seem to solve the issue:

```
 <match url="^folder" />
```

**This is what my 2 rules look like now:**

```
<rule name="NAME_folder" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^folder$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/folder" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="https://cnn.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
<rule name="NAME_folder1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^folder1$" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/folder1" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" appendQueryString="false" url="https://foxnews.com" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

On entry with both URLs (`folder` and `folder1`) - the user is redirected to the URL for `folder`  - even if i switch  the order of the rules in the file.
Thanks

Comment: You don't need that condition. Simply modify `url` in `match` tag to match the folder name.

Comment: @LexLi Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the below rule:

```
<rule name="rule12" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^folder" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cnn.com" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this cover a case where there are 2 folders, such as `zoom` and `zooming` - which would each have their own separate destination?

Comment: Also - i dont need it case specific... `Zoom` and `zoom` are the same

Comment: @kneidels yes you could create another rule for the folder zooming if the destination url is different.  `<rule name="rule12" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^folder2" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cnn.com" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>`

Comment: yes, i understand. but way the rule appears now a folder that starts with `zoom` and `zooming` get caught in the same rule, even though separate rules appear for each.

Comment: @kneidels try to set the pattern as  <match url="^zoom$" />

Comment: No - that did not solve the issue. I updated my question with the current code.

Comment: @kneidels you just need the match url. you don't need to use the condition. `<rule name="rule12" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^folder1$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.cnn.com" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>`